# How to sendl notifications to an admin within a web application, after a user has uploaded a file

Tags: mysql, laravel

In my document archive system, i want the admin user to be notified every time a user uploads a document so that they can approve it.

This is a laravel project, version 5.4 and am using a xampp server and mysql.

no code to display.

A notification will be sent to the admin each time the user uploads a file.

Comment: Read more about [Notifications](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/notifications). Essentially you want to dispatch an Event each time someone uploads a document and probably a Listener that handles sending the notification.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in mailing system if you want the admin to be notified by mail.

```
Mail::to($admin)->send(new fileUpload($upload));
```

Another option is to use [Laravel's notifications](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/notifications).